# MediaPlayer Video Problems

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've just spent about 2 hours trying to get this to work. I've never had much luck with getting videos to play with `MediaPlayer`. What am I doing wrong here? It plays just audio the first time through, no video. And then on the second time I get `IllegalStateException`'s when I try to re-`setDataSource`. I've tried not calling `stop()` and `release()` in `onCompletion` I've tried calling `reset()` before playing. I just get different StateExceptions (0, 64, 128) I've run out of ideas.

```
private void playVideo() {
    mMediaPlaying = true;
    sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //surfaceview
    try {
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        }
        mp.setDisplay(sh); //surfaceholder
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        mp.setDataSource(getBaseContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test));
        mp.prepare();
        //mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d("", "mp prepared");
    mp.start();

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    sv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mMediaPlaying = false;
    Log.d("", "Done playing media");

}
```

Comment: Ok, I removed the if(mp.isPlaying()) and added mp.reset() and it plays audio the first time, and on the second time it plays a split second of audio and then i get "media server died" "error (100,0)" "Error (100,0)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I basically copy/pasted [this here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) and it seems to be working... Except the first time it plays there is still no video... But I got rid of the errors :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use VideoView if you want to play video.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html

And you can use MediaController to control the video such as play,pause,forward and rewind.

Check this link for example.

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-videoview-to-play-mp4-from-sdcard.html

Comment: I don't want controls and I need OnCompletionListener which videoview lets you set but it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: You can use Oncompletion listener in VideoView

Answer (score 0):

mp.reset() must be call before setDataSource,
have a look at the life cycle  of MediaPlayer
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void playVideo() {
mMediaPlaying = true;
sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //surfaceview
try {
    if(mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDisplay(sh); //surfaceholder
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);

    mp.setDataSource(getBaseContext(), Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test));
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
```